# How to read lines from TXT file via scriptlet?

Tags: javascript, jsp, scriptlet

I've got flow in HP OO, which task is read some data from TXT file and show them on display. I'll try do it with FOR loop, but program received error:

```
Scriptlet error at line 1.
Code: for(int x=1; x=17; x++)
Details: missing ; after for-loop initializer
In step: PowerShellScript
```

The code of my scriptlet:

```
for(int x=1; x=17; x++)
{
     System.out.println.("C:\Users\tester01\Desktop\report.txt".Line[x]);
}
```

Probably code in for loop is not correct, but I actually want to run this loop.

Comment: `x = 17` should be `x < 17` and `x=1` should probably be `x=0` as array index starts at `0`

Comment: Unless you have created a **Line** indexer overload extension for type string, that reads string as file input - this does not work. (**Hint:** can not be done in Java). Also "System.out.println.(" is invalid syntax.

Comment: I know, but data which I want to get had started in line 1.

Even I've got comment (//) in my loop, it still have error in first line.

Comment: That's why I said "should probably" :)